# Missed A Connection

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

I work at a local newspaper in NY, and we do have a 'missed connections' section.
Today someone called and requested three ads at once. I hastily wrote them down:

First Ad:

> Saw you on the train.
>   Felt sparks fly.
>   Can't imagine life without you anymore!

Second Ad:

> Met you at the doctors.
>   Felt like you saw right through me.
>   Want to meet you again when I feel better.

Third Ad:

> Overheard your conversation while at work.
>   Just couldn't talk to you.
>   I like your taste in music and wish we could dance together.

While trying to keep up with all of his ads, it slipped my mind to ask for a name, so people would know whom to contact...

**Can you help me figure out who called me to place these missed connection ads?**

*If you figured out the recipients and struggle to find the caller:*

> The caller is (unlike the recipients of the ads) a real person.

*Another small hint:*

> The caller obviously has an *interest* in all of the recipients.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Puzzling :-). I'm really not sure this is considered as a riddle. Did you read the wiki info about the tag [tag:riddle]?

Comment: Yeah I did, and i am pretty sure that each ad would be considered a riddle.

Comment: Well, three lines with no rhymes are not considered as riddles in my mind, but I won't rollback again. Hope someone will confirm my thoughts though.

Comment: @IAmInPLS actually, I'm thinking the opposite. I don't see why this wouldn't be a riddle

Comment: @IAmInPLS Riddles don't have to rhyme, they just sound better when they do :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first ad is

> Electricity (probably talking about the '3rd rail'

The second ad is

> an X-ray 'saw right through me'

The third ad is

> Radio is something you frequently hear at work, has music and conversation and you can't 'talk to' it.

I'm guessing that the overall riddle has to do with

> Electromagnetic waves, since it includes both X-rays and Radio waves.

The caller could be

> Someone who studied all of these things. Possibly Nikola Tesla?

Comment: You correctly identified the recipiants of the ads, and i admit it might be a bit of a stretch to figure out the man who called - but as a hint: It was indeed a literal man. I will add a hint for this.

Comment: That was his name! Thank you. Now i can put his ads in the paper.

Title: missed A C onnection. <- i read it is considered good sport to put something in the title that relates to the solution, so you might spot it if you have already figured it out.

Comment: Well done! I didn't think of that

Comment: I'd have gone with Conductor for the first ad, for double meaning (train/sparks) and still fitting the riddle.

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer**

The First Ad looks like

> Electricity (sparks... and the train could be electric-powered, I can't imagine living without electricity)

The Second Ad looks a lot like

> X-Rays

The Third Ad

> ?? no clue yet

Who is the person calling?

> I don't know yet

Comment: You are on the right track! The first two ads are correct.

Answer (score 3):

I might have figured out the person but think I got the riddles

1.

> Rail, used for trains, sparks would fly if the train braked
>
> EDIT @oleslaw worked out it was electricity

2.

> X-ray, at doctors and sees through you

3. (Less sure)

> Phone, overheard conversation with someone else on the phone but can't talk to you, and stores your music
>
> EDIT @MMAdams worked out it was radio

So the man could be

> Heinrich Hertz - the man who proved the existence of electromagnetic waves

Comment: The second one is correct, the others not so much.

Comment: @Timme okay, now all the riddles are answers I've had a shot at the man. Doub it's correct though

Comment: It's close - but not who i had in mind.
I feel like you might have added a layer of abstraction when finding common ground in all three answers instead of just naming a person who has a literal interest in those three things. Maybe this will help - if no one gets it soon, i might choose this answer as correct, since otherwise this might end up as a game of 'guess the physicist' since most of them arguably are interested in those things..

Comment: @Timme I forgot to mention, welcome to puzzling! Nice first puzzle as well